# Reqexp in Perl not replacing the whole numeric characters but leaves the last digit as it is

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to eliminate the numbers from the following text:

```
This is a test for eliminating numbers from the text, the numbers are 3 1044 232 10.5
```

using the Perl code for regexp

```
$split1[$j] =~ s/\A[0-9]+\B/ /g;
```

I should be getting the output as

```
This is a test for eliminating numbers from the text, the numbers are 10.5
```

as 10.5 is not purely a number but also has a period to it. But the output that I am getting is

```
This is a test for eliminating numbers from the text, the numbers are 3    4   2  0.5
```

Comment: \A means "start of string", so I don't really see how you can possibly get your stated result by applying that regexp to the string at the top. Anyway, \B means "not a word boundary", which is why numbers that are just before word boundaries get excluded.

Comment: I am really sorry Calle I forgot to mention about the for loop that goes above this.
Sincere Apologies
But how can I get the desired results as I have tried using it without the \B but in that case still the single digit is not read and appears in the result text

Comment: When I try running the regexp with both \A and \B removed on your example string as a whole, all number are removed (as expected). So there's something else going on in the code you haven't posted that messes things up for you.

Comment: In general, when you have a regexp that you don't understand why it's not matching, `Regexp::Debugger` is an extremely useful module.

Comment: I can't remove \A and \B from my code as want the numbers that are to be removed from the text to be individual numbers only and not any number that constitute an alphanumeric.
So removing \A and \B can't be done.
Please suggest some way out

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you still keep some of the numbers because you use `\B`, which means *"not a word boundary"*, so all the numbers that are in front of word boundaries are being kept. That being said, I don't get the result you stated on your string, because you are using `\A`. The regex would not find any of your numbers because you told it to look for it *"at the beginning of the string"* with `\A`.

If you just want to get rid of integers, no matter where in your string they occur, you can use one of these two:

```
$split1[$j] =~ s/[0-9]+//g;
$split1[$j] =~ s/\d+//g;
```

A regex that would find any number, including floating point, would look somewhat like this:

```
$split1[$j] =~ s/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+//g;
```

Comment: Thanx Prawn but what about the alphanumerics, I want them intact

Comment: sorry, i didn't think of alphanumeric words because there were none in your example. `s/\b[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b//g;` wouldn't hit alphanumeric words. although i must say that @mpapec 's regex is probably more exact.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for editing. one of my first answers in this forum, so it's nice to see how an answer should look like.